# Global type inference in the Scheme compiler Stalin

Tags: types, compiler-construction, scheme, hindley-milner

I am looking into the Scheme compiler Stalin. It is big and complex. Also, if I understood correctly, the author was planning to write a series of papers detailing aspects of the implementation, but never got around to doing that.

The aspect of Stalin I am interested in is global type inference: deducing the types of things based on their usage in other places in the program. Does Stalin indeed do that? If yes, how, and where in its code base? Does it use a variant / extension of a Hindley-Milner algorithm?

Comment: Have you seen [this Q/A pair over at cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9765/the-stalin-compiler-brutally-optimizes-but-how)? It basically suggests that Stalin doesn't need to build "up" from types as such, it already infers *everything* about the value and its usage.

Comment: @Leushenko thanks! I think you are right: it seems that this compiler "skips" the concept of types, and works on primitive data type dispatches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/barak/stalin/blob/master/README):

> Stalin does global static type analysis using a soft type system that
>   supports recursive union types.  Stalin can determine a narrow or even
>   monomorphic type for each source code expression in arbitrary Scheme
>   programs with no type declarations.  This allows Stalin to reduce, or
>   often eliminate, run-time type checking and dispatching.  Stalin also
>   does low-level representation selection on a per-expression basis.
>   This allows the use of unboxed base machine data representations for
>   all monomorphic types resulting in extremely high-performance numeric
>   code.

From a [1997 talk by Siskind](http://www.njpls.org/feb97.html):

> Stalin performs type inference using set-based analysis (SBA aka
>   0CFA). This analysis is augmented to support polyvariant procedure
>   splitting. The results of SBA are used to reduce run-time type
>   checking and dispatching. The results of SBA are also used to do
>   low-level representation selection on a per-expression basis. This has
>   two benefits. First, type tags can be eliminated for monotypes,
>   allowing the use of base machine representations for primitive
>   data. Second, boxing can be eliminated, alleviating the costs of
>   indirection, allocation, and reclamation associated with
>   boxing. Eliminating boxing requires that the run-time organization
>   allow variables, parameters, structure slots, and vector slots to have
>   different widths depending on the type of data that they
>   hold. Furthermore, user-defined structures can be unboxed only if
>   those structures are immutable. SBA is extended to determine data
>   widths and mutability at compile time.

The actual type inference algorithm seems to be mostly implemented in the source
file `source/stalin3b.sc`.

It seems that SBA/0CFA is an entirely separate algorithm to
Hindley-Milner.  However, Hindley-Milner can also be used to implement soft typing.

Here's a nicer [description of the 0CFA
algorithm](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-kcfa-and-0cfa/).

Relevant papers are Olin Shivers' 1991 PhD thesis *Control-flow
Analysis of Higher-Order Languages or Taming Lambda* and Flanagan &
Felleisen's 1995 paper *Set-Based Analysis for Full Scheme and Its Use
in Soft-Typing*.